# Android ListView.smoothScrollToPosition() stops prematurely when it reaches a list item that is larger than the visible screen area

Tags: android, listview

I'm performing smoothScrollToPosition(int position) on a ListView and the list usually scrolls to the desired position. However, if while scrolling to the given position it passes a list item whose height is greater than the visible screen area, it simply stops at that list item. Any ideas about what might be causing this?